# Failed to parse source list when i run android

Tags: android, react-native

i use this command : `react-native run-android` and get this Error when start react native app in android:

> Failed to parse source list at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
>   Errors during XML parse:
>   White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.]
>   Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.

why it has problem with parsing this xml file that is standard and made by google. this error is making my crazy

**Edit:** I should to add this prompt of Error apologies for my reckless mistake:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

Answer (score 0):

My Problem Solved With This:
**Download and install JDK 8 or newer**
**Use a VPN**
Then:

1. Go to your React native Project -> Android
2. Create a file `local.properties`
3. Open the file
4. paste your Android SDK path like below

   - in Windows `sdk.dir = C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk`
   - in macOS `sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk`
   - in linux `sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk`

Replace `USERNAME` with your user name

Now, Run `react-native run-android` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

remove `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`from AndroidManifest.xml